# MySQL: Multiple SUMS Counting Combined Values WHERE Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
article_vote table
+------------+------+
| article_id | vote |
+------------+------+
|          1 |    3 |
|          1 |    1 |
|          1 |   -1 |
|          1 |   -2 |
+------------+------+
```

In MySQL 5.5 I've been trying to return two results from the above table. 1. The combined value of all negative votes. 2. The combined value of all positive votes. So positive should be **4** and negative should be **-3**. The vote field has no NULL values.

This SQL does not work as I intend:

```
SELECT vote,
    SUM(vote > 0) AS positive,
    SUM(vote < 1) AS negative
FROM article_vote
WHERE vote_article_id = 50
GROUP BY vote
```

when I use it on the above dataset it returns:

```
Array ( [vote] => -22 [positive] => 0 [negative] => 1 )
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct something like this:

```
select article_id, 
  sum(case when vote >0 then vote else 0 end) as postive,
  sum(case when vote <0 then vote else 0 end) as negative
FROM article_vote
GROUP BY article_id
```

Uncrear about your where condition,sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
SELECT
    SUM(if(vote > 0, vote, 0)) positive,
    SUM(if(vote < 0, vote, 0)) negative
FROM article_vote
WHERE article_id = 1
```

Result:

```
| POSITIVE | NEGATIVE |
|----------|----------|
|        4 |       -3 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62df8/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM article_vote;
+------------+------+
| article_id | vote |
+------------+------+
|          1 |    3 |
|          1 |    1 |
|          1 |   -1 |
|          1 |   -2 |
+------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN vote > 0 THEN vote ELSE 0 END) AS positive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN vote < 0 THEN vote ELSE 0 END) AS negative
FROM article_vote
WHERE article_id = 1;

+----------+----------+
| positive | negative |
+----------+----------+
|        4 |       -3 |
+----------+----------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c18e3/1

Comment: I choose this over mosty's. Thank you for this. Rep up :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT article_id,

    (SELECT SUM(vote) 
     FROM article_vote 
     WHERE vote > 0 
     AND article_id = 50) AS positive,

    (SELECT SUM(vote)
     FROM article_vote
     WHERE vote < 0
     AND article_id = 50) AS negative

FROM article_vote
WHERE article_id = 50
GROUP BY article_id
```

Comment: I think `SELECT DISTINCT article_id, ...`  would be nice.

Comment: @TrungDQ the `GROUP BY` clause takes care of duplicate rows. This should only return one row.

Comment: This return only one row. So if you remove all starting from "FROM", it still will be SAME result.

Comment: @TrungDQ I modified the `GROUP BY` clause about the same time you posted your comment. I think we misunderstand one another.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that... Anyway, nice query.